# django form not showing in template to add data

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

the goal of my code is to make a school management system where the admin can log in and add teachers to their respective classes that they are leading and be able to add students to their respective classes and then take the attendance of those students present on any given day. however, I am having an issue where the form to add the student to the class isn't rendering when I click on the add student button. I have been searching but can't seem to find the error in my code, I am new to Django so any help will be appreciated. the closest I got was to make the modal show up but the fields to select the student from to add to the class wasn't showing

**models**

```
class Teacher(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=False, null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=False, null=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    birth = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=[('Male', 'Male'), ('Female', 'Female')], blank=True, null=True)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=10000, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name}"


class Student(models.Model):
    student_code = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    admission = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    birth = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    parents = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=[('Male', 'Male'), ('Female', 'Female')], blank=True, null=True)
    comment = models.TextField(max_length=10000, null=True, blank=True)
    passport = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True, default='default.png', upload_to="profile/")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name}"

    def save(self, *args, **kawrgs):
        super().save(*args, **kawrgs)

        img = Image.open(self.passport.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.passport.path)


class Room(models.Model):
    form_teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    school_year = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    level = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __str__(self):
        return "[" + self.level + "] " + self.level + '-' + self.name


class ClassStudent(models.Model):
    classIns = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.student.student_code

    def get_present(self):
        student = self.student
        _class = self.classIns
        try:
            present = Attendance.objects.filter(
                classIns=_class, student=student, type=1).count()
            return present
        except:
            return 0

    def get_tardy(self):
        student = self.student
        _class = self.classIns
        try:
            present = Attendance.objects.filter(
                classIns=_class, student=student, type=2).count()
            return present
        except:
            return 0

    def get_absent(self):
        student =  self.student
        _class =  self.classIns
        try:
            present = Attendance.objects.filter(classIns= _class, student=student, type = 3).count()
            return present
        except:
            return 0


class Attendance(models.Model):
    classIns = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=' ')
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=' ')
    attendance_date = models.DateField(default=' ')
    type = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=[(
        '1', 'Present'), ('2', 'Tardy'), ('1', 'Absent')], default=' ')
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.classIns.name + "  " + self.student.student_code
```

**views**

```
 # create a classroom
login_required()
def class_view(request):
    form = ClassRoomForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClassRoomForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            name = form.cleaned_data.get('name')

            messages.success(request, f'{name} was Successfully Added')
            return redirect('classroom')

    classes = Room.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'school/class_view.html', {"form": form, 'classes': classes})
#show all the classroom created
@login_required
def class_detail(request,pk):
    _class = Room.objects.filter(id=pk).first()
    students = ClassStudent.objects.filter(classIns =_class).all()
    print(students)

    context = {
        'class': _class,
        'students': students
    }

    return render(request, "school/class_info.html", context)

#passes the form responsible for adding student to the classroom
@login_required
def save_class_student(request):
    form = SaveClassStudent()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SaveClassStudent(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Student has been added successfully.")
            redirect('class_detail')
      
    return render(request, 'school/class_info.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms**

```
class ClassRoomForm(forms.ModelForm):
    school_year = forms.CharField(max_length=250,help_text = "School Year Field is required.")
    level = forms.CharField(max_length=250,help_text = "Level Field is required.")
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=250,help_text = "Class Name Field is required.")


    class Meta:
        model = Room
        fields = ('form_teacher', 'name', 'level', 'school_year')

class SaveClassStudent(forms.ModelForm):
    classIns = forms.IntegerField()
    student = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = ClassStudent
        fields = ('classIns', 'student')

    def clean_classIns(self):
        cid = self.cleaned_data['classIns']
        try:
            classIns = Room.objects.get(id=cid)
            return classIns
        except:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Class ID is Invalid.")

    def clean_student(self):
        student_id = self.cleaned_data['student']
        _class = Room.objects.get(id=self.data.get('classIns'))
        student = Student.objects.get(id=student_id)
        try:
            cs = ClassStudent.objects.get(classIns=_class, student=student)
            if len(cs) > 0:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    f"Student already exists in the Class List.")
        except:
            return student
```

**HTML template for the form**

```
{% extends 'school/dashboard.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}
{% load humanize %}

{% block title%}

<title>Class Information</title>

{% endblock %}

{% block page%}Class Info{% endblock %}
{% block card%} {%endblock%}


{% block table %}
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="card card-default rounded-0 shadow ">
        <div class="card-header">
            <div class="d-flex w-100 align-items-center justify-content-between">
                <h4 class="card-title fw-bold">Class Information</h4>
                <div class="tools">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary border rounded-0 bg-gradient btn-sm"
                        id='print_attendance_report'><i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print Attendance Report</button>
                   <a href="#addModal" data-bs-toggle="modal"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary rounded-0 bg-gradient btn-sm" id='add_new'><i
                            class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Student</button></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <fieldset id="class-details">
                    <legend>Class Details</legend>
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="d-flex w-100">
                                <div class="col-auto pe-2 text-muted">School Year:</div>
                                <div class="col-auto flex-shrink-1 flex-grow-1">
                                    <p class="m-0 fw-bold">{{ class.school_year }}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="d-flex w-100">
                                <div class="col-auto pe-2 text-muted">Level:</div>
                                <div class="col-auto flex-shrink-1 flex-grow-1">
                                    <p class="m-0 fw-bold">{{ class.level }}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="d-flex w-100">
                                <div class="col-auto pe-2 text-muted">Name:</div>
                                <div class="col-auto flex-shrink-1 flex-grow-1">
                                    <p class="m-0 fw-bold">{{ class.name }}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="d-flex w-100">
                                <div class="col-auto pe-2 text-muted">Faculty:</div>
                                <div class="col-auto flex-shrink-1 flex-grow-1">
                                    <p class="m-0 fw-bold">{{ class.form_teacher}}</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <hr>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Class Student List</legend>
                    <table class="table tables-bordered" id="student-list">
                        <colgroup>
                            <col width="10%">
                            <col width="25%">
                            <col width="25%">
                            <col width="10%">
                            <col width="10%">
                            <col width="10%">
                            <col width="10%">
                        </colgroup>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="text-ceter">#</th>
                                <th class="text-ceter">Student Code</th>
                                <th class="text-ceter">Student Name</th>
                                <th class="text-ceter">Total Tardy</th>
                                <th class="text-ceter">Total Absent</th>
                                <th class="text-ceter">Total Present</th>
                                <th class="text-ceter">Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {% for student in students %}
                            <tr class="">
                                <td class="text-center">{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
                                <td>{{ student.student.student_code }}</td>
                                <td>{{ student.student.first_name }} {{student.student.last_name }}</td>
                                <td class="text-center">{{ student.get_present|intcomma }}</td>
                                <td class="text-center">{{ student.get_tardy|intcomma }}</td>
                                <td class="text-center">{{ student.get_absent|intcomma }}</td>
                                <td class="text-center">
                                    <button class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm delete-data" type="button"
                                        data-id="{{ student.pk }}" title="Delete">
                                        <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block content%}

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="addModal" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1"
    aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">Add Student To Class</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <form class="row g-3" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}

                    <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
                        <label class="form-label">Student</label>
                        {% render_field form.student  class+="form-control" %}

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Place</button>
                    </div>


            </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: In save_class_student you need to add else to if request.method == POST with form = SaveClassStudent()

Comment: @WaldemarPodsiadło didnt solve it

Comment: I'm already seeing a few issues with the code you've uploaded. But show the `html` file that is rendering the form.

Comment: @Damoiskii i have added the html as you asked

Comment: Okay, which of the `views` passing the form to the template?

Comment: save_class_student is passing the form @Damoiskii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few recommendations. Firstly, within your `forms.py` you're re-creating the existing fields and that's not necessary. For example:

```
class ClassRoomForm(forms.ModelForm):
     # school_year = forms.CharField(max_length=250,help_text = "School Year Field is required.")
     # level = forms.CharField(max_length=250,help_text = "Level Field is required.")
     # name = forms.CharField(max_length=250,help_text = "Class Name Field is required.")

     # There's no need to re-create the above since they're in the Room model already.

    
     class Meta:
         model = Room
         fields = ('form_teacher', 'name', 'level', 'school_year')
          
         # What you need to do is to use the widget attribute on the Class Meta to set the help_text and the max_length.
         widgets = {
              'name': forms.TextInput(attr={'class':'form-control'}, max_length=250, help_text='Class Name Field is required.'),
              'level': forms.TextInput(attr={'class':'form-control'}, max_length=250, help_text='Level Field is required.'),
              'school_year': forms.TextInput(attr={'class':'form-control'}, max_length=250, help_text='School Year Field is required.'),
         }
```

You could take that approach for the other forms you have as well.

Secondly, since you mentioned that the `save_class_student` method is passing the form, I'd suggest using `{{ form.student }}` if you want to render the form field of the form you're passing to the template.

```
<form class="row g-3" method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     ...
     <label class="form-label">Student</label>
     {{ form.student }}
     ...
</form>
```

However, I think you might want to pass the form from the `class_detail` method since you want it to be displayed with the existing class information based on what you have in your template. With this, you could have the `save_class_student` method to handle the `post request` instead of trying to pass the form from there. For example:

```
@login_required
def class_detail(request,pk):
     _class = Room.objects.filter(id=pk).first()
     students = ClassStudent.objects.filter(classIns =_class).all()
     
     # The classroom data: Initilizer
     data = {
          'classIns': _class  # To set the classroom on the form since you'll be displaying on the student field.
     }

     form = SaveClassStudent(initial=data)

     context = {
         'class': _class,
         'students': students,
         'form': form,
     }

     return render(request, "school/class_info.html", context)
```

Then within the `html` file, you can have the form's action calling the `url` for the `save_class_student` method.

```
<form class="row g-3" method="post" action="{% url 'save_class_student url here' %}">
     {% csrf_token %}
     ...
     <label class="form-label">Student</label>
     {{ form.student }}
     ...
</form>
```

Comment: sad to say the {{ form.student }} didn't fix it for me. the issue is still present

Comment: It seems like the `save_class_student` method isn't the method that is passing the form. Try passing the form from the `class_detail` method instead. I've updated my answer. Tell me what happened there.

Comment: it work thanks. seems like the first view was preventing the second one from parsing to it

Comment: another issue arise where the students aren't being added to the form in other words the form isn't saving but when I use the Django admin and add the students through the classStudent form it works perfectly fine and shows the students in the table but it doesn't work in the user Ui

Comment: That's a new question that should be asked bro. So post a new question with the related issue.

Comment: according to the site, I have already asked 4 questions which I didn't I only edited my post like 3 times so can't post question for few days :(